# Weird vibrations for Rig Arms

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I am new to blender and trying some basic animation. But having some wierd behaviors I am not able to fix. Can anyone help. The arms of the rig is having very wierd vibration in a point I dont even have a joint (bone).

Check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD6Qt.jpg

I dont have any key frame for those ofcoz.

Plz help this is really frustrating coz I redo the whole thing and it appeared again.

Blender: 2.9

Thanks

Comment: hello, hard to say, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry, the site is not working for a 100mb size file it keeps on processing after upload. Here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jc7vimt4kfw06t/Scene1.zip?dl=0 . Also, the vibration only occurs when I render a large section of the scene. If you just render 100 frames or less it won't happen for some reason. Here is the minimum frame range I rendered and vibration occurred: 151-660

Comment: I can't tell, I've rendered from frame 100 to 700 and it seems to work fine, I hope someone will find... by the way, instead of sharing your whole file, you could have shared just the character  ;)